# What is the current block level pushed by the Michelson instruction `LEVEL`?

Tags: michelson

What is the meaning of "current" in the description of the michelson instruction `LEVEL`:

> `LEVEL`: Push the current block level

Answer (score 3):

`LEVEL` pushes the level of the block that contains the current transactions.

We can verify this by originating a contract that only stores the level as returned by `LEVEL`:

```
$ tezos-client originate contract lvl transferring 0 from bootstrap1 running \ 
    'parameter unit; storage nat; code { DROP; LEVEL; NIL operation; PAIR; }' \
    --burn-cap 1 --force --init '0'
$ tezos-client bake for bootstrap5
```

It's initial storage is set to 0. We now send a transaction to this contract:

```
$ tezos-client transfer 0 from bootstrap1 to lvl
$ tezos-client bake for bootstrap5
```

Now, the level of the last block is the same as the storage of the contract:

```
$ tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header/ | jq .level
45
$ tezos-client get contract storage for lvl
45
```